# Sending mass/push message from server to client in DART lang using web socket [multi sockets]

Tags: websocket, dart

In my app, I dedicated the footer in the client side to receive messages/notification from the admin, I thought of using the web socket [multi sockets], but the msg is sent back to one socket only, i.e. the msg is sent back to the same socket that sent it, and not sent to other sockets, hope the attached file present the issue in a simple way.

note: All sockets are responding to socket onOpen and onClose, the bug is in the response of the onMessage!

[image]

my code is:

server.dart:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';  // for DateFormat

class myClient {
      WebSocket _socket;

     myClient(WebSocket ws){
            _socket = ws;
            _socket.listen(messageHandler,
                           onError: errorHandler,
                           onDone: finishedHandler);
     }

     void write(String message){ _socket.add(message); }

    void messageHandler(String msg){  
         print('a client sent this msg $msg');
         distributeMessage(msg);
    }

    void errorHandler(error){
         print('one socket got error: $error');
         removeClient(this);
        _socket.close();
    }

    void finishedHandler() {
         print('one socket had been closed');
         distributeMessage('one socket had been closed');
         removeClient(this);
         _socket.close();
    }
}


List<myClient> clients = new List();

 void main() { 
      HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4, 8080).then((HttpServer server) {
        print("HttpServer listening...");
        server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
          if (WebSocketTransformer.isUpgradeRequest(request)){
              WebSocketTransformer.upgrade(request).then(handleWebSocket);
           }
      else {
            print("Regular ${request.method} request for: ${request.uri.path}");
            serveRequest(request);
            }
        });
     });
 }

void handleWebSocket(WebSocket socket){
  print('Client connected!');
  myClient client = new myClient(socket);
  addClient(client);
}

void serveRequest(HttpRequest request){
  request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN;
  request.response.reasonPhrase = "WebSocket connections only";
  request.response.close();
}

void distributeMessage(String msg){
   var now = new DateTime.now();
   var timeStamp = new DateFormat("[dd-MMM @h:mma]");
   String formatTime = timeStamp.format(now);   
   for (myClient c in clients)c.write('${timeStamp.format(now)}: $msg ');
 }

 void addClient(myClient c){
     clients.add(c);
 }

 void removeClient(myClient c){
      clients.remove(c);
 }
```

the client.dart file is:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
       Element fonixFooter = querySelector('#fonix-footer');

       String server = 'ws://localhost:8080/';
       WebSocket ws = new WebSocket(server);
       ws.onOpen.listen((Event e) => fonixFooter.text='Connected to server');   // this is fine

       ws.onMessage.listen((MessageEvent e){        <= this is not functioning!!
          print('msg is: ${e.data}');
          fonixFooter.innerHtml=e.data;
       });

      ws.onClose.listen((Event e) => fonixFooter.text='Connection to server lost...');   // this is fine

   }
```

the admin.dart is:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

 void main() {
      TextInputElement input = querySelector('#input');
      ParagraphElement output = querySelector('#output');

      String server = 'ws://localhost:8080/';
      WebSocket ws = new WebSocket(server);
      ws.onOpen.listen((Event e) {
      outputMessage(output, 'Connected to server');
  });

  ws.onMessage.listen((MessageEvent e){
      outputMessage(output, e.data);
  }); 

  ws.onClose.listen((Event e) {
     outputMessage(output, 'Connection to server lost...');
  });

  input.onChange.listen((Event e){
     ws.send(input.value.trim());
     input.value = "";
   });
}

 void outputMessage(Element e, String message){
      print(message);
      e.appendText(message);
      e.appendHtml('<br/>');
      e.scrollTop = e.scrollHeight;
 }
```

based on @luizmineo feedback the he tested the server side, I noticed my code is working if and only if each socket sent some data, the socket that is not sending data, not receiving anything, but still do not understand why! and how to fix it!

Any thought, where I made the mistake!! any recommendation about better approach is appreciated.

Comment: I've tested your server implementation and it seems to work fine (although, you can also take a look at higher level websocket APIs, such as redstone_web_socket and shelf_web_socket). 

I've also noted that your client.dart script uses the fonixFooter.innerHtml property to show received messages, and fonixFooter.text to show connection status. Maybe this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks @luizmineo, I used fonixFooter.text for all, still same issue, moreover I opened another admin socket, it is not exchanging msgs with the first admin socket, unless it sends data to the server, I added an input field to the client to send msg to the server, and the msg got recieved in all sockets, in simple words, I noticed my code is working if and only if each socket sent some data, the socket that is not sending data, not receiving anything, but still do not understand why! and how to fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by asking each socket to send something to the server upon connecting, so I've the below codes:

in main.dart and client.dart, changed the onOpen to be:

```
ws.onOpen.listen((Event e) => ws.send('Connected to server'));
```

in the server.dart changed the message handler to be:

```
  void messageHandler(String msg){  
    if (msg == 'Connected to server')write('Connected to server');   // send msg to the new socket only
    else distributeMessage(msg);  // send msg to all opened sockets
  }
```

I believe this is a work around solution, hope to hear direct answers!